# How to do percentage in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, percentage

I'm trying to create a query. I have two tables

- `customer` (`customer_id`)
- `rental` (`rental_date` (timestamp), `customer_id`)

```
SELECT   to_char( rental_date, 'Month') AS month, 
         (count(Distinct customer.customer_id)/
           (count (distinct rental.customer_id) * 100) 
         ) AS percentage
FROM RENTAL,customer
GROUP BY month;
```

But the result is zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When all "numbers" involved in an operation are integers, the result will be an integer too.

Try this way:

```
SELECT 
  to_char( rental_date, 'Month') AS month, 

  (
    count(distinct customer.customer_id)::float / 
   (count(distinct   rental.customer_id)::float * 100::float) 
  ) 
   as percentage 

FROM 
  RENTAL,customer 
GROUP BY month;
```